# Magento 2: We were unable to validate your address

Tags: magento2

I am facing issues while adding an address to address book in magento2 user account area. When I try to add a new address to address book, it throws the following error.
How to disable address verification in Magento 2?
Or at least tell me what is this connection error?

[image]

Its going here when save address button is clicked.
http://***/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/validate-address

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem:
There was an extension "Classyllama" This was the cause of the issue. When I disabled it no validations anymore.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

Go System > Configuration > on the right side, click on Tax > Scroll down to Shipping Address Options > Under Address Validation, select Disabled > click Save

**Your Magento store will not longer validate addresses.**

Comment: On magento 2.2.3 Sales option is under Store > Configurations.
But still that option is not there.
I figured out the issue after a lot of debugging. There was an extension "Classyllama" This was the cause of the issue. When I disabled it no validations anymore. Just wondering why its validating address even its not active from admin panel.
but thanks for the help anyway!